# Index was outside the bounds of the Array VB.NET Program to calculate data in database

Tags: sql, mysql, database, vb.net, sql-server-2008

So I had this program (VB.NET) to process/calculate data from a database. After several looping and iteration, it comes to an issue "Index was outside the bounds of the Array." I tried to find it online but there's only solution for those who use SQL Query by upgrading their SSMS version or SQL Client, but its not a program related issue. Is there any possibility to solve this by changing or updating configuration or setting in the server? Thanks!
[Index was outside the bounds of the Array.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4BdC.jpg)

Is there configuration in the server or any other option to solve this issue.

Comment: You need to use the debugger to work out the basics of the issue for yourself. Do you know what array it's referring to? Do you know what the bounds of that array are? Do you know what index was being used at the time? These are things that are all at your fingertips but you've made no indication that you have looked at all. If you don't know how to debug, stop what you're doing and learn that first. Debug your code and do what you can for yourself first. If you still need help then provide us with ALL the relevant information, which would include the offending code.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not retrieving as many records as you think.

For example, if you are looking at the first/only record, but no records were returned by your query.

Or you have a loop that assumes at least one record matches your query.

It might be worth performing a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... WHERE ...` query first, to check whether any records match.